# Find relations between columns in pandas datafarme

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
RING    CLLI    RR          root            CIRCUIT
N100    M200    200.1       OC1             Circuit1
N100    M200    200.1       OC1             Circuit2
N100    M201    200.2       OC1             Circuit3
N100    M202    200.3       OC1             Circuit1
N101    M300    300.1       OC2             Circuit1
N101    M304    301.8       OC2             Circuit11
N101    M147    500.5       OC2             Circuit10
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit11
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit114
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit113
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit112
N104    M643    414.1       OC8             Circuit2
N104    M643    414.1       OC8             Circuit234
N104    M643    414.1       OC8             Circuit11
```

I want to check for example, If column CIRCUIT is repeated in other rows. If it is repeated, and the RING is different, I want to add another column and tell what is the CLLI of that Circuit.
In the end, the final dataframe would look like this:

```
RING    CLLI    RR          root            CIRCUIT           NeigbourCLLI
N100    M200    200.1       OC1             Circuit1            M300
N100    M200    200.1       OC1             Circuit2            M643
N100    M201    200.2       OC1             Circuit3            NaN
N100    M202    200.3       OC1             Circuit1            NaN
N101    M300    300.1       OC2             Circuit1            M200
N101    M304    301.8       OC2             Circuit11           M874, M643          
N101    M147    500.5       OC2             Circuit10           NaN
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit11           M304, M643
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit114          NaN         
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit113          NaN
N102    M874    568.7       OC4             Circuit112          NaN
N104    M643    414.1       OC8             Circuit2            M200
N104    M643    414.1       OC8             Circuit234          NaN
N104    M643    414.1       OC8             Circuit11           M874, M304
```

I have tried this code but it is not that good and it is also iterating a lot and my dataframe is huge, it is taking a lot of time:

```
ring_clli_dict = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    circuit = row['CIRCUIT']
    ring = row['RING']
    clli = row['CLLI']
    if circuit in ring_clli_dict:
        if ring != ring_clli_dict[circuit]['RING']:
            ring_clli_dict[circuit]['NeighbourCLLI'].append(clli)
    else:
        ring_clli_dict[circuit] = {'RING': ring, 'NeighbourCLLI': [clli]}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    circuit = row['CIRCUIT']
    if circuit in ring_clli_dict:
        df.at[index, 'NeighbourCLLI'] = ', '.join(ring_clli_dict[circuit]['NeighbourCLLI'])
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

**UPD:**

Okay, this one works fine, but as i mentioned, my DF is 500k rows and using such a code, it taking ages to finish....

```
grouped = df.groupby('CIRCUIT').apply(lambda x: x['RING'].nunique() > 1)

def find_neighboring_cllis(row):
    circuit, ring = row['CIRCUIT'], row['RING']
    if grouped[circuit]:
        neighbors = df[(df['CIRCUIT'] == circuit) & (df['RING'] != ring)]['CLLI'].unique()
        if neighbors.size > 0:
            return ', '.join(neighbors)
    return np.nan

df['NeigbourCLLI'] = df.apply(find_neighboring_cllis, axis=1)
```

Is it possible to make it faster and use a more "pandas" solution instead of going row by row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates(['RING','CIRCUIT']).groupby('CIRCUIT')['CLLI'].transform(lambda x: [set(x)]*x.size)
df.assign(NeigbourCLLI = (s - df['CLLI'].map(lambda x: set([x]))).str.join(',').where(lambda x: x.ne('')))
```

Output:

```
    RING  CLLI     RR root     CIRCUIT NeigbourCLLI
0   N100  M200  200.1  OC1    Circuit1         M300
1   N100  M200  200.1  OC1    Circuit2         M643
2   N100  M201  200.2  OC1    Circuit3             
3   N101  M300  300.1  OC2    Circuit1         M200
4   N101  M304  301.8  OC2   Circuit11    M874,M643
5   N101  M147  500.5  OC2   Circuit10             
6   N102  M874  568.7  OC4   Circuit11    M643,M304
7   N102  M874  568.7  OC4  Circuit114             
8   N102  M874  568.7  OC4  Circuit113             
9   N102  M874  568.7  OC4  Circuit112             
10  N104  M643  414.1  OC8    Circuit2         M200
11  N104  M643  414.1  OC8  Circuit234             
12  N104  M643  414.1  OC8   Circuit11    M874,M304
```

Comment: This works just fine, there is no same circuit in the same RING. But if we have another, for example Circuit1 in RING N100, in the NeighborCLLI, it will M200,M300. The condition i need to check it is that if the CKT is the same, and RING is different, then add the CLLI value to the new column. Could you please check also this one. I have also updated the initial dataframe...

Comment: Please check my updated question, I have provided a working code, but it is slow, maybe you know a better way to handle it?

Comment: What if we add another condition? Can we make it so that, We only add the NeigbourCLLI, only if the NeigbourCLLI is equal to the actual CLLI. Maybe the mock data is not that good, i have not provided such example, but would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Using top 5 rows only:
data={"RING":["N100","N100","N100","N101"],
"CLLI":["M200","M200","M201","M300"],
"RR":["200.1","200.1","200.2","300.1"],
"root":["OC1","OC1","OC1","OC2"],
"CIRCUIT":["Circuit1","Circuit2","Circuit3","Circuit1"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

# Creating a dictionary
to_map=df.groupby("CIRCUIT")["CLLI"].agg(set).to_dict()
df["NeigbourCLLI"]=df["CIRCUIT"].map(to_map)

df['NeigbourCLLI']=df.apply(lambda x:''.join([i for i in x.NeigbourCLLI if i not in x.CLLI]),axis=1)
df['NeigbourCLLI'].replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)

print(df)
    RING    CLLI    RR  root    CIRCUIT NeigbourCLLI
0   N100    M200    200.1   OC1 Circuit1    M300
1   N100    M200    200.1   OC1 Circuit2    NaN
2   N100    M201    200.2   OC1 Circuit3    NaN
3   N101    M300    300.1   OC2 Circuit1    M200
```

Comment: This works just fine, there is no same circuit in the same RING. But if we have another, for example Circuit1 in RING N100, in the NeighborCLLI, it will M200,M300. The condition i need to check it is that if the CKT is the same, and RING is different, then add the CLLI value to the new column. Could you please check also this one. I have also updated the initial dataframe...

Comment: Please check my updated question, I have provided a working code, but it is slow, maybe you know a better way to handle it?